# ImageField not working for Django version 2.0.4

Tags: django, django-models

I am using Django version 2.0.4 but I am facing a problem with `models.ImageField`.

Whenever I try to update an existing image with a new one, nothing happens. Also when I try to clear the image, nothing happens.
I have all the dependencies installed like Pillow.

I have declared my ImageField as usual like -

```
class Community(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=upload_location,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        width_field="width_field",
        height_field="height_field", help_text="A image representing the Community")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

I have used ImageField before, but haven't ever faced such an issue ever. Is this a problem with the Django version? Should I consider upgrading my Django version? 
Thanks in advance

#### Update

Things I have tried - 
I have tried a different database.
Tried upgrading the Pillow version

Comment: I think it's not the problem from version. Do you get some error message?

Comment: No no errors come

Comment: Your image uploaded well?

Comment: And are you using dev environment right now?

Comment: Could you post your HTML file and view function ?

Comment: @seuling For the first time, its getting uploaded, but when I try to change it or clear it, nothing happens and no errors come

Comment: @seuling yes I am testing it on dev, but its not working in production either, just in case if you were thinking it might be because of media urls and MEDIA_ROOT

Comment: @Deadpool I am not saving the model in a view , I am just testing it out on the admin panel

Comment: You defined something in Admin panel but you don't have `admin.ModelAdmin` ? Something strange

Comment: @Deadpool no , I have other fields as well and that are working fine, and not only in this model but I've one other model in which I'm facing the same problem, I'm not sure why, maybe because of version, not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. I did implement the save method in the admin.py as

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if change:
        obj.updated_by = request.user
    else:
        obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.updated_by = request.user
        obj.save()
```

which was causing the problem. I fixed it by calling the save_model of the super class like this -

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
    if change:
        obj.updated_by = request.user
    else:
        obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.updated_by = request.user
        obj.save()
```

I know I should have called this function before, but it was a good learning for me to call it everytime necessary

Answer (score 0):

**You can upload or update an image in Django the following way:**

*models.py file*

```
class ImageModel(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="profile pics/", null=True, blank=True)
```

*image.html file*

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
 </form>
```

*This is how I used to upload / update images in my project.*

**Hope things work well. Cheers!**